# Mongoid, get distance from models in kilometers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have model `Shop` which has this field for geolocation:

```
 class Shop
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :location, type: Array

   index( { location: '2d' }, { min: -180, max: 180 })
   before_save :fix_location, if: :location_changed?
   def fix_location
    self.location = self.location.map(&:to_f)
   end
 end
```

I have created indexes for my models.

Then I want to find shops which are around 50 kilometers:

```
  distance = 50 # km
  loc = [lat, lng]

  Shop.where(location: {"$near" => loc , "$maxDistance" => distance.fdiv(111.12)})
```

This method works fine and gives my models that I need. However, how to determine how far (in kilometers) are they from my location?

Do I need to use aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the MongoDB $near operator already sorts documents by distance, you could simply calculate the distance in your Rails server for each of the documents returned by your query, for instance using [the Haversine gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/haversine) .

```
distance = 50 # km
loc = [lat, lng]
loc_lng_lat = [lng, lat]
Shop.where(location: {"$near" => loc_lng_lat , "$maxDistance" => distance.fdiv(111.12)}).each do |shop|
    shop_lat_lng = [shop.location[1], shop.location[0]]
    distance = Haversine.distance(loc, shop_lat_lng)
    # do what you want with the distance
end
```

Notice the swapping of latitude and longitude, because MongoDB expects 2D geo arrays to be in the format of [longitude, latitude], while again the Haversine gem expects [latitude, longitude]